# Disabling UIButton not working

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, isenabled

The solutions i'm finding on here use `.enabled` which is old, rather than `.isEnabled`.

So i'm currenting trying to just disable the functionality/clickability of buttons if a certain condition is (or isn't) met. So before it all I disable them all if a condition isn't met then if there on after (dynamically) it is met then it should theoretically enable. That being said, it is not initially disabling the buttons when I start off with `.isEnabled = false`.

I know the condition is being met because I have print statements and other tests (like labels being removedfromsuperview yet `.isEnabled = false` for the buttons isn't working. Anyone encountered said problems or have any solutions?

Code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    trumpMoneyDefault.setValue(50, forKey: "TrumpMoney")
    print("UnoViewController")
    //make all the buttons that shouldn't be clickable unlcickable
    locklvl2.isEnabled = false
    locklvl3.isEnabled = false
    trumplvl2.isEnabled = false
    trumplvl3.isEnabled = false
    lvl2.isEnabled = false
    lvl3.isEnabled = false

    //make level2/3 unclickable by defeault
    //lvl2.isEnabled = false
    //lvl3.isEnabled = false
    //update trumpmoney label depending on if they have enough cash
    //also here check if they have already unlocked all via purchase of unlock all. If so, then skip all this
    if trumpMoneyDefault.value(forKey: "TrumpMoney") != nil
    {
        trumpmoney.text = trumpMoneyDefault.value(forKey: "TrumpMoney") as? String

        //remove locks if they got the money by default.
        let tempTrumpMoneyDefault = trumpMoneyDefault.value(forKey: "TrumpMoney") as! Int
        if tempTrumpMoneyDefault >=  100
        {
            locklvl2.removeFromSuperview()
            moneylvl2.removeFromSuperview()
            trumplvl2.removeFromSuperview()
            lvl2.isEnabled = true
            if tempTrumpMoneyDefault >=  500
            {
                locklvl3.removeFromSuperview()
                moneylvl3.removeFromSuperview()
                trumplvl3.removeFromSuperview()
                lvl3.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your actual code of how you are trying to disable your buttons?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Just edited it in!

Comment: @instacatering are those references to buttons from Storyboard/xibs? i.e, how is `locklvl2` declared?

Comment: Without a broader context it's hard to say, but should you be doing this in *viewDidLoad*?

Comment: @Edgar Yes IBOutlet drag and drop.

@ dfd I don't think it would cause any issues as I can call UILabel functions and other direct UIButton functions in it.

Comment: @instacatering you are calling `removeFromSuperview()` on a view owned by the view controller's view from the Storyboard via IBOutlet. I believe once you call `removeFromSuperview()` that button becomes dealloc'ed since nothing is holding it strongly (your IBOutlet references are probably `weak` right?

Comment: If it's IBOutlet, have you tried setting disabled in the storyboard? If so, does it work when implemented that way?

Comment: @Edgar No they are strong. the removefromsuperview isn't on the buttons i'm having issues with. That part is working literally perfectly fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really? It should work.

1.)This is how I disable a button and it's working.

```
myButton.isEnabled = false;
```

2.)Desperate way to disable button by disabling the user interaction.

```
myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
```

Comment: .isUserInteractionEnabled = false/true worked for me :D

Answer (score 3):

`.enabled` is a previous Swift versions way of determining whether the button is disabled or not.

**Swift 3**

Use `.isEnabled = true`
or `.isEnabled = false` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: That's what I stated in the question haha. I was basically saying that I couldn't use previous stack questions/answers because they used old swift.

Comment: My bad - completely misread. I would take the code outside of the `ViewDidLoad`, and try putting it inside a `ViewDidAppear` method.

Comment: I've been able to call many other UIButton functions inside of the viewdidload so I don't see difference in this case :/

Comment: Have you tried putting it inside the `viewWillAppear` method? - I don't think that it should be called in the `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: that didn't change a thing. I tried, didn't help :/

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but I couldn't find any solution to my bug, so here it is. For anyone who uses Storyboard, be sure that `UIButton`s don't have multiple `@IBOutlet` and there is no intersection among them. That could happen if you were lazy and duplicated the button.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a UITextField, no matter what I did I couldn't disable it.

The solution that worked for me was to clean the build folder.

I'm using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2